# Flask + SQLAlchemy - Is there a way to dynamically change which databases I have a connection to?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am on a new project, and we are in the process of creating a web application from an old desktop application. Mind you, I didn't design any part of the old application. One of the requirements is for a client to connect to 4 separate databases (each has a specific purpose and set of data). These databases store information unique to each user's session whenever a they run the application. The end user can also create a new session and chose another set of these databases to run analysis on.

I've been trying to find a way to recreate this paradigm that the desktop application currently uses except now trying to use Flask to serve our GUIs instead. I already attempted to use Flask-Session to store SQLAlchemy engine objects so I can later update them on the fly, but engine objects are not picklable.

I know I can write a function that will run `create_engine()` and return a new `Session` using `sessionmaker()` but it seems very dirty to create an engine for every single request. I'm stuck on how to proceed with being able to do this using SQLAlchemy.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish would look something like this but **these database connections need to be unique per client using the web application**:

```
db1 = create_engine('sqlite:///database1.db')
db2 = create_engine('sqlite:///database2.db')
db3 = create_engine('sqlite:///database3.db')
db4 = create_engine('sqlite:///database4.db')

# Some logic and functions

def update_dbs():
    db1 = create_engine('sqlite:///new_database1.db')
    db2 = create_engine('sqlite:///new_database2.db')
    db3 = create_engine('sqlite:///new_database3.db')
    db4 = create_engine('sqlite:///new_database4.db')
```

Comment: what do you mean the connection has to be unique per user? are you creating multiple databases per user session? 

What would usually be done imo is maintain a single `create_engine` object per database and then give the users access to each database (giving them the `create_engine` object, in your case the `db1..4` variable). Sqlalchemy automatically does some pooling of connections and you can config it.

If you are always creating new databases however, then you need a new connection (`create_engine`) per new database.

Comment: What I mean by "give the user the variable" is that whatever function is handling the users request gets that variable

Comment: @Matthias Each user can have 4 separate database connections. So if we have 10 users, there is the potential to have 40 separate database connections. Each of these connections need to be unique per user session.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure on the details of your intended setup, are you using Flask like an API to serve your web application?

Comment: if that's the case the method I proposed in my first comment should work fine :)) like I said sqlalchemy/flask automatically does pooling for you, meaning it can definitely handle 40 database connections (at least if you add it to the config). I'm using something called `flask_sqlalchemy` and get the engine like this: `engine = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app).engine`, and the api endpoints use this object

Comment: I also don't see a problem with creating a connection per session per database per user if you'd rather do that. That's entirely possible, you just need some code to handle the sessions and give them out

Comment: We ended up discussing a similar solution at work after we explained the situation to another team. For now, we'll just create the engine for every API request to get the functionality working. But long term, we'll do something similar to what you had suggested and have some sort of ConnectionManager that will keep track of all the database connections.

Comment: Alright good you came to a conclusion. If you ever do solve it, might be nice to post an answer here so others can benefit

Comment: We only just started working on this web application so it might be a month or two before I can post an answer for others who run into this same issue.